# Gekko Moria's whereabouts?

Tags: one-piece

Does anyone know exactly what hapened to Gekko Moriah? IIRC he was in the Marineford arc. But I haven't seen anything of him post time-skip?

Did I miss some development or something?

Answer (score 3):

The last we saw of Moriah was

> him attacked by Doflamingo and a group of Pacifista in the backstreets of Marineford. According to Doflaminog this was because Moriah was deemed "too weak"to continue serving as a Shichibukai. When asked by Moriah is Sengoku ordered this, Doflamingo told him that it came from someone higher than him. [Chapter 581/Episode 490]

Perona asks Mihawk about Gekko Moriah

> Mihawk tells her that Moriah was alive at the end of Battle, but he is not sure if he is still alive now. The newspaper reports that Moriah is dead

Doflamingo however later reveals to the Gorosei,

> that Moriah escaped before he could deliver the killer blow, probably using his DF power. He also asserts that Moria was critically injured and die anyways. [Chapter 595/Episode 513]

Thus Moriah's official status is **Unknown**. Doflamingo believes he is dead, but according to **[New World Times](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/New_World_Times)**, Moriah survived and is in hiding somewhere in the New World. This is however based on eyewitness accounts and thus NOT a confirmation.